# Swift - alternative to dispatch_after

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, watchkit

Swift/SO newbie here - will try to be clear!

I have an `@IBAction` being called from a `wkinterfacepicker`. This calls a function which may make a change to the picker again - which in turn causes the `@IBAction` to be triggered again, and so can result in unwanted loop-type behaviour.

What I am trying to do is to have control *pass* to the second func, rather than be *called from/return to* the `@IBAction` function. I have a working solution using `dispatch_after`, implementing an arbitrary delay so that the `@IBAction` finishes before the second func starts, but this does not seem very elegant/appropriate.

Here is roughly what that looks like:

```
@IBAction func freePickerChanged(value: Int) {
    selectedValue = value

    let triggerTime = (Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC) * 1)
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, triggerTime), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.changeValues()
    })
    // Without using dispatch_after, program control returns here from changeValues(), causing loop
}

//Ideally would call changeValues() here, after @IBAction exits

func changeValues() {
    //Do some calculations here. Perhaps the picker needs to be changed again using setSelectedItemIndex -  @IBACTION KICKED OFF AGAIN
}
```

Is there a better way to pass control to the second function from the @IBAction func as it exits? Or maybe I am just on the wrong track completely?

Thanks in advance for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: What do you mean by "Without using dispatch_after"? dispatch_after schedules a block on the provided queue and returns immediately. What did you expect to happen? Did you think the program would wait one second, run the block and then go to the line you have your comment on?

Comment: No, I understood that. I was just trying to clarify what happened if I _didn't_ use `dispatch_after` -  i.e. just calling the func changeValues would go run the func then return here, which is the problem (behaviour) I am currently using `dispatch_after` to overcome. Perhaps that comment adds confusion rather than clarity.  But I am essentially using `dispatch_after` now to 'wait a second' just to allow the `@IBAction` call to complete before changeValues commences. This seems a poor solution to me, hence looking for suggestions.

Comment: The times when I want to do this, rather than deciding how long to wait - I `dispatch_async()` a block onto the main queue. That way the block won't be executed until the current run loop completes.

Comment: Thanks Abizern. I had messed with `dispatch_async`, but I can't remember what queue I was using! I'll give your suggestion a try and let you know.

Comment: Your suggestion works to answer this question, but actually showed up that my issue is not what I thought.  The problem is not the order of execution, but may in fact be an bug with `wkinterfacepicker` whereby if you change the picker value using `setSelectedItemIndex` too quickly it vacillates between values a number of times, recalling the `@IBAction` each time.

Comment: I saw your solution was calling the functions one after the other as I had requested, but I was still seeing my 'looping' behaviour issue. So I tried with different values on 'dispatch_after' and a pause of 1sec (or more) seems to work, but anything less than that gives the same 'loopy' behaviour.

Comment: Abizern if you want to add this as an answer I will mark it correct as it did succesully answer the question I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than pick a random delay after which to run your code, another way to do this is to just put your block of code on to the main queue asynchronously. This will run after the current run loop completes so you don't have to work out how long to wait for.

i.e instead of

```
dispatch_after(...
```

try

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // your code here
}
```